# Riverpod Alternative To SetUpLocator

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, firebase-remote-config, riverpod

I want to call my `Remote Config` Instance on Flutter App StartUp
I have set up `Riverpod` as follows

```
class ConfigService {
  // Will Initialise here
  final RemoteConfig _remoteConfig;
  ConfigService(this._remoteConfig);

  Future<void> initialise() async {
  ...// Will fetchAndActivate
}

final remoteConfigProvider = Provider<RemoteConfig>((ref) {
  return RemoteConfig.instance;
});

final configProvider = Provider<ConfigService>((ref) {
  final _config = ref.read(remoteConfigProvider);
  return ConfigService(_config);
});
```

I would want to call it in the main after

```
...
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
... here
```

But this can't be done because one needs a `Reader` and the `ProviderScope` is below this level

How do I call this provider in my main ?

Comment: You can't. Why not just read it within the ProviderScope?

Comment: Alright @AlexHartford Can you please direct me to an example calling a provider in the ProviderScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. What you should do is call the Provider within the ProviderScope.

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final config = watch(configProvider);
    return Container();
  }
}
```